# Is there any way of removing the "," from an array when printed?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Was just wondering if there is any way that I can remove the "," in a printed array list in javascript?

Example:

```
var testArray = ["random", "random2", "random3"];
```

When printed:

```
random,random2,random3
```

Comment: Yes there is. But what language are you using? Also please post your attempts.

Comment: Ohh, woops i should have said. JS

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using javascript, `testArray.join(" ")` is what you're looking for. It joins your array into a string using the specified separator (here a white space).

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use a forEach as such:

```
testArray.forEach((element) => {
   console.log(element); });
```

Comment: If you're into arrow functions then `testArray.forEach(element => 
   console.log(element))` is less to type, but `testArra.join(' ')` is less again. ;-)

Comment: yeah i could also see that working, great suggestion.